# Create table in cassandra 2.0 cluster only exists on one node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We have a cluster with two nodes.
When I do a create table command, the table is actually only created on one node:

> CREATE TABLE prod.users_test (
>    user_name varchar,
>    password varchar,
>    gender varchar,
>    session_token varchar,
>    state varchar,
>    birth_year bigint,
>    PRIMARY KEY (user_name));

This used to work fine the last time we created a table on the cluster. It's been a while but nothing has changed.  The cluster has been working fine and data is being replicated between the two nodes in the older tables.

If I manually create the table on both nodes and do an insert on one node, it does get replicated to the other node.

Any idea why it's not getting created on both nodes now?

Here's the keyspace description:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE prod WITH replication = {
 'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
 'PRODDC1': '2' };

   CREATE TABLE users_test (
 user_name text,
 birth_year bigint,
 gender text,
 password text,
 session_token text,
 state text,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_name)
) WITH
 bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
 caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
 comment='' AND
 dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
 gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
 index_interval=128 AND
 read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
 replicate_on_write='true' AND
 populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
 default_time_to_live=0 AND
 speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
 memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
 compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};`
```

Here's the cassandra-topology.properties file:

```
10.6.71.204=PRODDC1:RAC2
10.6.71.205=PRODDC1:RAC2

# default for unknown nodes
default=PRODDC1:RAC2

# Native IPv6 is supported, however you must escape the colon in the IPv6 Address
# Also be sure to comment out JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
# in cassandra-env.sh
fe80\:0\:0\:0\:202\:b3ff\:fe1e\:8329=DC1:RAC3
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `desc keyspace prod` from CQL?

Comment: I updated the original post with the describe output

Comment: As I see, you use NetworkTopologyStrategy. Can you also post your cassandra-topology.yaml config?

Comment: We have the snitch set up in cassandra.yaml to be: `endpoint_snitch: PropertyFileSnitch`  Doesn't that mean it's the cassandra-topology.properties file?  I've updated the original post with it.